# How should I modify the dataSet of the BaseAdapter so notifyAll will take affect?

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm using `public class SettingValueAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

It has an array `private SettingsValue[] values;` as it's dataSet.

When the activity is visible I change the data (aka dynamically)

I use `notifyDataSetChanged` but the UI doesn't change.

I have seen an answer that I should use `ArrayList` and actually remove and reenter elements.

But I have an array and I can only reassign it or reassign elements in it.

I cannot change to ArrayList, as this is a common shared code and it will be too painful.

Does this really the issue? this is why my UI doesn't change dynamically?

in my Activity:

```
public void refreshListIcons() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (categories != null) {

                    SettingsValue[] values = adapter.getValues();
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                        values[i].icon = ResManager
                                .GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
                    }

                    adapter.setValues(values);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //mListView.invalidateViews();
                    //mListView.refreshDrawableState();

                }

            }
        });


}
```

Comment: The code looks correct, are you sure 'categories' is not null !!, and make sure 'ResManager.GetSkinDrawable' return changed data

Comment: make sure the data has changed, Log the 'values[i].icon' before and after in the for loop, are they really changed ?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
  SettingsValue[] values = adapter.getValues();
```

not really copy an array, it just refer to array of adapter. It's a reason why adapter doesn't fire change when set itself. Try copy an array like this one:

```
  SettingsValue[] values = Arrays.copyOf(adapter.getValues(),adapter.getValues().length);
```

Then notify change should work.

**Update**:
From [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29):

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

`notifyDataSetChanged` only works if you use the add, insert, remove, and clear functions on the Adapter. In this case, you replaced dataset in adapter so it may fire change.

**Update 2**: I have test my above code and `JafarKhQ` 's way, all of them worked fine. So, if your icon not update, I think there have a problem with set image method in your adapter. Try setting image for image view by resource name or resource id ( in getView method of adapter) like this:

```
 // Set image by string name, make sure string name don't have extension, for example: "icon1"
 ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
// find the id of resource image
 int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackage:drawable/" + arr[position].getImage(), null, null);
 img.setImageResource(id);
```

And here is `JafarKhQ` 's recommend, it should worked:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getValues().length; i++) {
       adapter.getValues()[i].icon = ResManager
                            .GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
       }

       // don't need set data set for adapter, just notify change.
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: But he change the 'icon' in each value, so he dosnt need to call 'adapter.setValues' function, but the data are changed ?

Comment: the doc you wrote is for "notifyDataSetInvalidated()", the "notifyDataSetChanged()" says "Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself."

Comment: Sorry, it's my copy mistake. Fixed it.

Comment: I think thats not true, i have tried it https://gist.github.com/JafarKhQ/5896645 and its work

Comment: @R4j at the beginning I created a new array named `values` and sent it to `adapter.setValues(values);` which include assignment to `adapter.values` and `notifyAll`. But it did'nt help. Any idea?

Comment: @JafarKhQ so what do you think I should change?

Comment: @Elad Benda have updated my answer, I think there is a problem when seting image from adapter.

Comment: @JafarKhQ Ok, I have tested my code and your code, they worked fine. Because `Elad Benda` want to use array from adapter by copy to a new one so I just fix a copy mistake of him.

Comment: @R4j I will try all you have written. But why did it work for me when I have created a fresh new array of `values` and assigned it to `adapter.values` and afterwards `notify`  ? it didnt work

Comment: what does this mean? `and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.` after `notify` another method invokation is needed on any view? is the list considered observer?